# How to cache my favicon

Tags: html, apache, apache2

Im trying to make my favicon cacheable as yslow suggets.

My favicon is http://www.tucoaster.com/favicon.ico

For some reason, the content type of the favicon is text/plain.
I'm using apache2, and in my .htaccess i have

```
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 30 days"
```

Note: Javascript and css headers are sent ok.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache may not know the right MIME type for the ICO format.

Try adding

```
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

before the `ExpiresByType` directives.

Comment: You're right.  To see what Apache thinks the MIME type is for favicon.ico, benchmark your web page using http://www.webpagetest.org/ and then click on "Details" and scroll to the bottom to see the Response Headers when favicon.ico was fetched.  Without the "AddType image/x-icon .ico" in .htaccess, Apache reports my favicon.ico as "Content-Type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon" instead of "Content-Type: image/x-icon".

Comment: What about ExpiresDefault instead of ExpiresByType? I am using ExpiresDefault and favicon.ico is still not cached. Actually, anything that is referenced in my index.html is not cached, while the rest which loads via requireJS is properly cached. I am actually totally out of ideas...